# Unable to resolve service for type 'Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'CustomerRepository'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

My Problem  define controler in  startup  but again dsiplay Error that  :Unable to resolve service for type 'Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'CustomerRepository'

Now I put my code below

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
  public CustomerRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
  {
  }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{

}

 public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        DbSet<TEntity> Entities { get; }
        IQueryable<TEntity> Table { get; }
        IQueryable<TEntity> TableNoTracking { get; }

        void Add(TEntity entity, bool saveNow = true);
        Task AddAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool saveNow = true);
       ...

    }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddMvc()
         .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
      services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
            services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();


      // services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
    }
```

I expected my code to work, but I am facing the following error. Thank you for your help

Comment: Your DbContext is not added to the IServiceCollection. Use IServiceCollection.AddDbContext<>(..) to add it. Check the docs of your db for details on the configuration options.

Comment: I solved my case by adding this part of the code

Answer (score 0):

I solved my case by adding this part of the code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(op =>
        op.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer")));

      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
      services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
      services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**